# merge mongodb aggregate result

Tags: mongodb

I have one collection say `user`. Structure of each document is something like this

```
_id:String
status:Int32
account:{
    firstName:
    lastName:
    .. some other nested property
}
..some more property
```

My end goal is to generate a new nested field `fullName` in `account`field which is a concatenation of two name fields. I can run `aggregate` query like this

```
db.user.aggregate(
[
  { $project: { 'account.name': { $concat: [ "$account.firstName", "  ", "$account.lastName" ] } } }
])
```

if I write `$out` along with db name, but my existing data get replaced. How do I actually merge so that my final structure remains as

```
_id:String
status:Int32
account:{
    firstName:String
    lastName:String
    fullName:String
    .. some other nested property
}
..some more property
```

Answer (score 1):

In your **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline, you need to include the other fields using the dot notation on the [embedded fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#embedded-document-fields) as follows:

```
db.user.aggregate([
    { 
        "$project": { 
            "status": 1,
            "field1": 1, // the other properties
            "field2": 1,
            "account.firstName": 1,
            "account.lastName": 1,
            "account.name": {"$concat":["$account.firstName", "  ", "$account.lastName"]}  
        } 
    },
    { "$out": "tempcollection" }
])
```